# What is the difference between shannon fano and huffman algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, compression, information-theory, lossless-compression

It look likes almost similar to me except top down and Bottom-Up parsing . Can anyone explain ?

Comment: (This looks *assignment* as in *you will learn something figuring this out yourself*.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is indeed the fundamental difference.

In Huffman encoding, codes are built bottom up by repeatedly combining the two least common entries in the list of populations until only two are left.

In Shannon-Fano, the population list is sorted by pop count and then repeatedly (recursively) split in two - with half the population in each half, or as close as one can get - until only two entries are left in a sub-section.

Huffman has been proven to always produce the (an) optimal prefix encoding whereas Shannon-Fano is (can be) slightly less efficient. Shannon-Fano, on the other hand, is arguably a bit simpler to implement.